# Can I have purchased Unity assets on my Github repo?

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, assets

So I recently purchased an asset pack in the Unity Asset Store. When I push my project to Github, would it be fine if those assets are included in it? I'm just worried if someone would be able to clone the repo and use the assets for free

Comment: In theory: As soon as it is an asset/unitypackage nobody can hinder you from sharing this with other people on GitHub etc ... Regrading GitHub .. if you wan to make your projects private I would suggest you rather use Gitlab (personal opinion though) there you can make projects private and only share them with coworkers

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the licence but generally no, you cannot publically share the code you bought access to, this is usually explicitly said in the licence